# if value contains a certain number

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to write a macro that would change result depending on a value. 
The numbers are 5 digits and can only be 1 , 2 or 3

if numbers are all 1 then the result would be pass.

if numbers contains 2 then the result would be action.

if numbers contains 3 then the result would be fail.

**eg:**

11111 result is **pass**

11211 result is **action**

32111 result is **fail**

This is the code(below) which i have created but i am not sure how to use that InStr control or even if i should be using that

```
Private Sub result()
   Dim points As Integer, result As String

    Me.txtresult.Value = Val(cboImage.Value) & Val(cbofruit.Value) & Val(cboveg.Value) & Val(cboProcedure.Value) & Val(cboDescription.Value)
    points = Val(Me.txtresult.Value)

    Select Case points
        Case InStr(1, 1)
            result = "Pass"
        Case InStr(1, 2)
            result = "Action"
        Case InStr(1, 3)
            result = "Fail"
    End Select
    Me.txtresult.Value = result
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if this works. I have replaced the `Select` block with an `If` block

```
Private Sub result()
Dim points As Integer, result As String

Me.txtresult.Value = Val(cboImage.Value) & Val(cbofruit.Value) & Val(cboveg.Value) & Val(cboProcedure.Value) & Val(cboDescription.Value)
points = Val(Me.txtresult.Value)

If InStr(points, "3") > 0 Then
result = "Fail"
Else
    If InStr(points, "2") > 0 Then
    result = "Action"
    Else
    result = "Pass"
    End If
End If
Me.txtresult.Value = result
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a macro for this? A forula like this can give the desired result:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("3",A1)),"FAIL",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("2",A1)),"ACTION","PASS"))
```

assuming your value is in cell A1.

Comment: thanks for your reply but my value does not go in to one cell, i am using a form which has 5 drop down lists that have only 1 2 3 to choose from so if either one  of those has a 2 it would make it an action if either number has a three it would be fail